# How do you activate Mylyn in the current Eclipse perspective?

Tags: eclipse, mylyn

I installed Mylyn but it doesn't seem to be activated in my current perspective. How do I do this?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You'll need to open the relevant Mylyn views which are the Task List and Task Repository Views.  To open a view use Window -> Show View.  Once you have these views open add a task repository in the Task Repository View and then add a query in the Task List View, which will download relevant tasks.  When you begin working on a task, i.e., by activating that task, you will notice that a focus button is added to several views, such as the package explorer.  If you press the focus button only task-related files will be shown in that view.

This video walks you through getting setup: http://tasktop.com/videos/1.6/setup/tasklist/

This video shows you how to work task-focused: http://tasktop.com/videos/1.6/setup/focus/

Answer (score 3):

You need to open the Mylyn views (task list & task repositories).

Answer (score 1):

Look in the `Preferences / Customize Perspective / Command Groups Availability` dialog.

Do you see:

- Java Task Context
- Task Context
- Task Navigation

They must be set, for Mylyn task management to be visible.

Comment: In a similar topic, see also http://blog.mxunit.org/2010/02/best-eclipse-menu-youve-never-heard-of.html

Comment: Does Preferences / Customize Perspective / Command Groups Availability exist in Helios?  I don't see it.